# How to view a part of the map in natural size using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, arcgis-10.3, printing

I have a map project in ArcGIS 10.3. My project page size is custom 1500 * 1000 mm.

How can I cut a part of this map to print it on A4 format paper and see this part with a natural resolution (same as it will be in 1500 * 1000 mm size)?

EDIT: Added picture for clearing what I want.
[image]

Comment: By natural size/resolution I am wondering whether you are wanting to set a reference scale.  Perhaps look that up in the help and see if it is what you are after.

Comment: After seeing the picture; you should use the answer from @wittich below. The key for you is to set the scale the same in both exports!

Comment: If you don't want to mess around with changing your project or making a new one, just export to pdf and then use the Adobe snapshot tool to print to A4 with Page Scaling set to None in the print dialog box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [fix your scale](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//006600000440000000) what ever you output format is, it will have the right scale (or what you called the natural resolution). Then set the [printing layout](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s900000007000000).

Otherwise you can use map series. Therefore I would create a [index feature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/na/00s900000025000000/) and set a enable [data driven pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Enabling_Data_Driven_Pages/00s90000002t000000/)

Comment: But that is about changing the page layout, not keeping the scale while doing so...

Comment: added the hint for the printing layout and the link. But as @Martin says it will only work correct if you setup the scale correct

Comment: Well, thx for ur tips. Anyway I left step by step instruction for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instruction for printing a little part of a huge map on A4 paper:

1. Prepare project for your huge map.
2. Go to `File` => `Page and Prints Setups` and change `Map page Size` to A4.
3. Leave same scale
   as in original huge project and move extent to region of interest and `Export map` to a file.
4. Print exported map on A4 paper.